# Sending text message in the background using app inventor?

Tags: android, app-inventor

Just started to play with app inventor 2 and I was wondering if it is possible in this framework to send text messages that are driven by a timer when the application is minimized?

So what I have are 3 times of the day stored in a database and when I minimize the app, I want text messages to be sent at the 3 times.

I can get this to work when the application is open but not when it minimized.

Comment: your question already has been answered in the [forum](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/yHuF69ITUaQ/uKlAfg0EUrcJ). Unfortunately I do not have a better answer for you...

Comment: this [workaround](https://puravidaapps.com/alarmmanager.php) could be interesting for you...